# How to add line break into placeholder text area?

Tags: rsform

How can I add a line break into the placeholder text area of the RSform?

Tried without success:

```
- \n
- <br/>
- &#10;
```

A sample of the form with the non working text area can be found here at the last page as guarantees field: [freelancer-form](https://www.xenovation.com/ads/jobs/supplier-freelancer-and-registration-form)

Answer (score 1):

Many people offer js and non-js solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7312623/2943403

Using a non-js technique may have different outcomes on different browsers -- specifically standards compliant versus non-compliant browsers.  The reason for this obstacle:

> The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry when the control has no value. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the expected format. The attribute, if specified, must have a value that contains no U+000A LINE FEED (LF) or U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) characters.

My cleanest recommendation is not to fight the placeholder attribute and just express the `e.g.` as plain text outside of the textarea tag or be content with asingle wrapping line of text.  This will likely provide an improved UX for visually impaired visitors.

p.s. I'll ask @sirobertson to advise about how we got our JoomlaDayAustralia2019 survey to correctly position the page after clicking Next.

Comment: do not get your point about JoomlaDay?

Comment: When I click Next on your form, the loaded page position is awkward.  My fellow event coordinator fixed this issue, but I don't know what he did.

Comment: ahh okay getting it. I have created a new issue for the new topic https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23987/rsform-with-multipage-form-is-not-jumping-to-the-top-of-the-form and many thanks for pointing to the new issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a CSS/jQuery workaround, and make the placeholder a div element with absolute positioning under the text area, and have the text area use a transparent background.

Then you change the textarea background to a solid color on focus, and use jQuery to detect if the textarea has any content. It must add a CSS class to the textarea if it is not empty, and remove that class if it's empty. The class will just define a solid color background.

Comment: do you have specific example for rsforms?