# RSform with multipage form is not jumping to the top of the form

Tags: rsform

If I create a new multi-page form in RSform the page switching is behaving non user centric.
Means if I click on "Next" in the form the form is, to staying at the bottom of the page instead of jumping to the top of the form on the new page.

How can I configure this behaviour to jump to the top of the form.
Ideally I can decide to jump to the top only if the user has not entered any values. So a user can quickly click through the form if he wants only to review the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form go to CSS and JavaScript and add this code

```
<script>

function rsfp_showPage(thePage) {
  RSFormProUtils.removeClass(thePage, 'formHidden');
  window.scrollTo(0, findPos(document.getElementById('userForm')));
}

function findPos(obj) {
  var curtop = 0;
   if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
        curtop += obj.offsetTop;
       } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
   return [curtop];
   }
}

</script>
```

Comment: thx this trick worked!